# immutable child from abstract parent

Tags: java

Can a `final` class that extends an `abstract` class be immutable?

For example:

```
public abstract class Parent {}

public final class Child extends Parent {}
```

Is `Child` immutable?

Comment: A class being `final` doesn't imply anything about it being immutable.

Comment: Why would you think that the subclass couldn't be final?

Comment: @ControlAltDel: If `Parent` is completely empty or is immutable itself then my guess would be that `Child` would inherit that immutability if `Child` was immutable as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "immutable?" A final class cannot be subclassed. A final variable cannot be changed. In this example Child is a class, not a member variable of some other class.

Comment: @MichaelTiffany: Why doesn't an immutable `Child` cause an empty `abstract` `Parent` to be immutable?

Comment: I'll ask again: what do you mean by "immutable?" You're using the word like it has some official definition in the Java language spec. It doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelTiffany: I mean that it's thread-safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutablility of the `Child` class is not controlled by `final` keyword for the class declaration. To make your class immutable, design it in that way, that its state cannot be changed as the class instance has been created.

Adding `final` to the class declaration, just makes impossible to extend your class.

For example:

```
public final class Child extends Parent {

   private final String someText; // final is not necessary there, but it is a good practice, to declare fields like this as final. Because it gets its value once, and does not change later.

   public Child(String someText) {
     super(); // calling parent's constructor
     this.someText = someText;
   }

   public String getSomeText() {
     return this.someText;
   }    
}
```

Note, that as you have created an  instance of `Child` class then you cannot change its contents. So, the class is immutable.

Answer (score 4):

It's not immutable.

It just can't be extended.

Immutable classes are defined so no method can mutate their internal state, e.g. `java.lang.String` (which also happens to be a `final class`).

Final classes cannot be extended. As a by-product, that's why you can't have a final `abstract class` or a `final interface`.

This usually helps ensuring immutability, but it's only co-related.

Finally, thread-safety is yet another feature, which doesn't necessarily require immutability and has even less to do with preventing inheritance.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) and child chapters for better insights on immutability.

**Note**

If your classes are completely empty through the inheritance hierarchy and your leaf class if `final`, it is factually immutable, since there's nothing to mutate.

It also is quite pointless, of course.

Comment: `java.lang.String` is declared `final` because it is necessary (but not sufficient) for an immutable class, is it not?

Comment: Even though `Parent` is completely empty, `Child` is still not immutable?

Comment: @gla3dr well not really. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html). **Edit** to clarify: making the class `final` makes it easier to make it immutable. But in theory it's not the only way, although alternatives (i.e. every field private/final) are not too typical.